# How to get User Details after Google Authentication in web app using firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a web-app that allows users to sign in using their gmail account.Once the user is signed in, I am able to see it's details using result.user object like this-

```
function signInWithGoogle(){

   var provider=new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
   firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result){

      var user=result.user;

      console.log("user_provider="+user.displayName+" user_email="+user.email+" user_dp="+user.photoURL+" user_verification="+user.emailVerified+" uid="+user.uid);

   }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("error="+error);
   });
}
```

After signing in, I want to keep user details in page even after reloading and refreshing for that I  used User object of auth() like this-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var user=firebase.auth().currentUser;
     console.log(user);
});
```

But it's showing user as null although I can see user email address in authentication console in firebase.

P.S. I have also used onAuthStateChanged instead of currentUser , but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

`onAuthStateChanged` should work. You have to listen to it correctly.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // currentUser should be available now.
  } else {
    // No user logged in.
  }
});
```

Keep in mind that the state is stored in single host origin web storage. So if you navigate to a page with a different domain, the state will not propagate.

Comment: means if I use onAuthStateChanged on different page of same website then it would give user as null ?

Comment: It's pretty clear. It has to be the same domain. Do you expect to sign in in example1.com and get the same user in example2.com?

Comment: no sign in from example1.com/page1.html  and get user details in example1.com/page2.html

Comment: In that case, the auth state should be shared by both pages. Make sure web storage is enabled. 3rd party cookies/data could be disabled and Firebase Auth falls back to in memory storage.